# Get When Notification Available

Tags: android

I'd like to create an external notification LED. I can handle the electronics and wireless communication between Phone and Micro controller easy. However, I'm unsure how to detect when there are notifications available. Perhaps the NotificationListenerService?

Comment: What is an Micro Controller? Phone receive push notifications.

Comment: I plan to send an instruction to turn an LED on to a micro-controller (e.g. Arduino) via bluetooth when the phone receives a notification, then another instruction to turn it off when the notifications are empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the best way to do this is by using the **NotificationListenerService**. It was introduced in Android 4.3 and it was considerably improved with lots of new features in Android 4.4. You should use it.

I will try to help you with a short tutorial on how to use it.

### How to Use

**Step 1**

You first need to extend the NotificationListenerService class and implement its methods.

```
public class SimpleKitkatNotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

        @Override
        public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
              //..............
        }

        @Override
        public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
              //.............. 
        }
}
```

**Step 2**

Then you must declare the service in the manifest file with the `BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE` permission and include an intent filter with the `SERVICE_INTERFACE` action.

```
<service
      android:name="it.gmariotti.android.examples.
            notificationlistener.SimpleKitkatNotificationListener"
      android:label="@string/service_name"
      android:debuggable="true"
      android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE" >
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.service.
                 notification.NotificationListenerService" ></action>
      </intent-filter>

 </service>
```

**Step 3**

You must authorize it from the user. You can find it in **Settings -> Security -> Notification Access**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS");
    startActivity(intent);
```

**Step 4**

Use the `extras` field to get any information you want to,

```
Notification mNotification=sbn.getNotification();
   Bundle extras = mNotification.extras;
```

You can get a lot of info from this class,

```
/**
     * {@link #extras} key: this is the title of the notification,
     * as supplied to {@link Builder#setContentTitle(CharSequence)}.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_TITLE = "android.title";

    /**
     * {@link #extras} key: this is the main text payload, as supplied to
     * {@link Builder#setContentText(CharSequence)}.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_TEXT = "android.text";

    /**
     * {@link #extras} key: this is a third line of text, as supplied to
     * {@link Builder#setSubText(CharSequence)}.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_SUB_TEXT = "android.subText";

    /**
     * {@link #extras} key: this is a bitmap to be used instead of the small icon when showing the
     * notification payload, as
     * supplied to {@link Builder#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)}.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_LARGE_ICON = "android.largeIcon";
```

**Step 5**

You can easily get data like this,

```
String notificationTitle = extras.getString(Notification.EXTRA_TITLE);
     int notificationIcon = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);
     Bitmap notificationLargeIcon = 
                  ((Bitmap) extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON));
     CharSequence notificationText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_TEXT);
     CharSequence notificationSubText = extras.getCharSequence(Notification.EXTRA_SUB_TEXT);
```